# How do I copy the error message I get from YCM

Tags: cut-copy-paste, plugin-you-complete-me

Is there a way to copy the error message that YCM shows at the bottom of vim?

[image]

For example in the above image, it says:

> unused parameter 'sortFunction'

I had an idea of using "howdoi [paste]" in another terminal and get a solution easily :)

Comment: `$ howdoi` won't help. You only need basic logic: you have an unused parameter so you have two solutions: remove it or use it.

Comment: @romainl no no , you took me wrong , I just wanted to demonstrate that case. Infact I've intentionally introduced that variable :p

Answer (score 6):

If YCM uses the proper mechanisms, that message should be in either `v:statusmsg` or `v:errmsg`. You can put those values into the system clipboard via:

```
:let @+ = v:statusmsg
```

Comment: says Invalid register name: '+' and I tried with ' * ' too and it says same.

Comment: That means your Vim doesn't have clipboard support. You could launch the command directly from Vim: `:! howdoi <C-R>=v:statusmsg<CR><CR>` then.

Comment: @lngo and how do I check I have clipboard support? if "vim --version|grep .xterm_clipboard -o" shows "-xterm_clipboard" doesn't it means I do have it? Found it over SO.

Comment: Okay but ":echo has('clipboard')" returns 0 so I don't have it :) , I'll recompile and report back.

Comment: Right; it would have to be a `+` in front. Is the message in one of those variables; have you checked that? Getting it out there is just secondary to your original question.

Comment: I do have Clipboard support now but `:let @+ = v:statusmsg` shows : `"/tmp/vT1CBzR/56.cpp" [New] 92L, 2224C written` :D and `:let @+ = v:errmsg` shows : `E31: No such mapping` :D. And I couldn't understand this " Is the message in one of those variables". I'm using YCM which predicts errors in my code by analyzing it with Clang. Would that help?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal You can check if YCM uses those variables by executing `:echo v:statusmsg` or `:echo v:errmsg`. If one of them contains the message you're looking for, use that variable. If both of them are empty, then YCM is not using these variables to store the error messages. Also, make sure you get the error message with YCM again as `v:errmsg` may get overwritten with newer error messages.

Comment: I guess YCM uses something else to display those message , I have tried numerous times to echo those message , found some other unrelated texts but not YCM's errors.

Comment: Then it's likely `:echo`. You could raise an issue at YCM's issue tracker to have that (trivially) changed to `:echomsg`.