# How can I copy the contents of an LSP / linter error message in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-typescript

I'm using TSServer with LSPConfig to provide in-line typechecking with Neovim.

Is there a way for me to grab the value of a given type error message?

Especially to my system clipboard?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! If the text is an "overlay" (or ghost text, or virtual text), I'm not sure it's easily copyable. But you can often run the linter/compiler/other program that produced the message directly. (FWIW: this is why I prefer popups to virtual text: the text is selectable.) One exception: you might be able to copy virtual text if it appears in a Vim inside tmux (using tmux's copy/paste features).

Comment: Similar question asked [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/discussions/24076) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/15xszia/copy_lsp_typescript_error_message_with_shortcut/).

Answer (score 1):

To open it as a floating window, do `:lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()`. If you do that again, you will move into the window. Then you can copy the line you need to the system clipboard with `"+yy`.

I have bound the above function to `<leader>e` as follows, so I would then do `<leader>e` twice to jump inside the buffer, and then copy as above:

```
local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
    local opts = {noremap = true, silent = true}
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<leader>e',
                                '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()<CR>', opts)
end
```

And then pass that to `lsp.clangd.setup { on_attach = on_attach }`. You should have your own vimrc/lua/custom_lspconfig.lua, where you add such LSP-bindings, so that they are only bound for the local buffer when an LSP is attached. [Mine is here](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/vimrc/blob/master/lua/custom_lspconfig.lua), if you want more context.

Answer (score 0):

See [this reply](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/how-do-i-copy-the-error-message-i-get-from-ycm)

That message should be in either `v:statusmsg` or `v:errmsg`,. You can put those values into the system clipboard via:

```
:let @+ = v:statusmsg
```

Comment: Thank you for writing an answer. The bulk of it is a quotation from the answer you refer to. I think your answer could be improved if you just wrote down your own observations (you did test this works?) and rephrased (e.g. "is" instead of "should")

Comment: you have misunderstood the question. This is not a duplicate of the other question you linked to. We need the message given by the LSP server, which is shown in floating red text, for example "header <iostream> not found in system paths" ... it is not a vimscript / lua error at all, it's just the floating text given by the linter or language server.